# ASP.Net webservice with SQL Server database connectivity

Tags: asp.net, .net, database, web-services

I'm a complete beginner in ASP.Net webservices can anyone point me to a good tutorial by which I may implement a web service with SQL Server database connectivity?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### 1. Create the Project in Visual Studio

go to   **Visual Studio>New Project**(select .Net Framework **3.5**) >**ASP.net Web Service Application**
This will create a web service with a `HelloWorld` example like

```
    public string HelloWorld()
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }
```

### 2. Create a Database and Obtain the connection string

### 3. Define WebMethod

To create a new method that can be accessed by clients over the network,create functions under `[WebMethod]` tag.

### 4.Common structure for using database connection

add using statements like

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

Create an `SqlConnection` like

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"<your connection string>");
```

create your `SqlCommand` like

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"<Your SQL Query>", con);
```

open the Connection by calling

```
con.Open();
```

Execute the query in a `try-catch` block like:

```
try
        {
            int i=cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            con.Close();
            return "Failed";

        }
```

Remember `ExecuteNonQuery()` does not return a cursor it only returns the number of rows affected,
for `select` operations where it requires a datareader,use an `SqlDataReader`  like

```
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

and use the reader like

```
using (dr)
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    result = dr[0].ToString();



                }
                dr.Close();
                con.Close();

            }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a video that will walk you through how to [retrieve data from MS SQL Server in ASP.NET web service](http://vimeo.com/14600650).